# How to install xgboost on Azure ML cluster webservice?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm using the new Azure ML Workbench and set of model management services doing a regular Python (not Pyspark) project.  I have a conda_dependencies.yml file which looks like this:

```
name: project_environment
channels: 
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  # The python interpreter version.
  # Currently Azure ML Workbench only supports 3.5.2.
  - python=3.5.2
  - scikit-learn  
  - xgboost
```

We deploying to my Azure cluster it never seems to install xgboost and thus when deploying the webservice I always get this error

```
File "/var/azureml-app/score.py", line 31, in init
    import xgboost
ImportError: No module named 'xgboost'
```

At the point where its calling my score.py to load my saved xgboost model.
Can someone explain to me how to get xgboost installed for this? The error occurs whether I create the environment step by step or via the single command as in this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/preview/tutorial-classifying-iris-part-3

This are the commands leading up to the error (the cluster has already been provisioned and set):

```
az ml manifest create --manifest-name oapmodelv1manifest -f score.py -r python -i <modelid> -s schema.json
az ml image create -n oapv1image --manifest-id <manifestid> -c aml_config\conda_dependencies.yml
az ml service create realtime --image-id <imageid> -n oapmlapp --collect-model-data true --debug
```

Comment: I wonder if you may also need to use the CLI to [run a configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/preview/experimentation-service-configuration-reference#run-configuration).

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to conda_dependencies.yml (works for me):

```
channels: 
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.5.2
  - scikit-learn
  - py-xgboost
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this some more and saw [this code](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningSamples-Iris/blob/master/aml_config/conda_dependencies.yml), so I wonder if you put `xgboost` under a `pip` section would work, like below:

```
dependencies:
  - python=3.5.2
  - scikit-learn
  - pip:
    - notebook
    - xgboost
```